# How do I get the current school hour and time remaining?

Tags: javascript, date, time

I have this function:

```js
function getInfoSchoolTime() {
 var date = new Date();
 var schoolBellTime = ["8:10","9:02","9:54","9:59","10:51","11:43","11:58","12:48","13:35","13:40","14:10","15:02","15:54"];
 var remainingTime, currentHour;

 for (var i = 0; i < schoolBellTime.length-1; i++) {
  var startTime = schoolBellTime[i].split(":");
  var endTime = schoolBellTime[i+1].split(":");

  if (parseInt(startTime[0]) >= date.getHours() && parseInt(startTime[1]) >= date.getMinutes())
   if (parseInt(endTime[0]) <= date.getHours() && parseInt(endTime[1]) <= date.getMinutes()) {
    currentHour = i;
    remainingTime=(parseInt(endTime[1])-date.getMinutes()+60)%60;
    break;
   }
 }

  if (currentHour == undefined)
  return {current: -1, remaining: "not available"};
 return {current: currentHour, remaining: remainingTime};
}

var info = getInfoSchoolTime();
console.log(info.current, info.remaining);
```

I have the `schoolBellTime` array that contains the timestamps of my school bell (I know, my school has strange bell times, these timestamps includes playtimes and lunchtime), this function is meant to return the 1st hour/2nd hour/3rd hour ... and the minutes that remains to the next hour/breaktime.

I checked all the code and can't find the error, it keeps returning `{current: -1, remaining: "not available"}`

Comment: Not sure it matters but `"9:2"` should probably be `"9:20"`

Comment: (removed my comment about off-by-one error, I just noticed what you're doing). Anyway this would be easily solved by using a debugger, no?

Comment: It will not skip the last element, the `endTime` var has the `i+1` in the schoolBellTime position

Comment: @Igor nope, `"9:2"`  it's meant to be 9:02 AM

Comment: Can you update your question and apply the fix?

Comment: Do you intend to include `'14:10'` twice?

Comment: Please also fix `15:2` while you are at it.

Comment: @Igor "9:2" is 9:02 AM so that's not the problem

Comment: No but it makes it difficult for anyone that wants to copy/paste your code and try to run it. It is unnecessary noise that can be easily fixed.

Comment: It's working fine when date hours, minutes matches

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function at the top: `setDateTime()` takes a date and a time, and constructs a date object for that time.

Then I updated your function, I convert `start` and `end` to times on the current day, and then check if `date.getTime()` occurs between them.  Then I simply subtract `date.getTime()` from `end`, and convert the result to minutes from milliseconds.

```js
var setDateTime = function(date, str) {
  var sp = str.split(':');
  date.setHours(parseInt(sp[0], 10));
  date.setMinutes(parseInt(sp[1], 10));
  return date;
}

function getInfoSchoolTime() {
  var date = new Date();
  var schoolBellTime = ["8:10", "9:02", "9:54", "9:59", "10:51", "11:43", "11:58", "12:48", "13:35", "13:40", "14:10", "14:10", "15:02", "15:54"];
  var remainingTime, currentHour, currentPeriod;

  for (var i = 0; i < schoolBellTime.length - 1; i++) {
    start = setDateTime(new Date(), schoolBellTime[i])
    end = setDateTime(new Date(), schoolBellTime[i + 1])
    if (date.getTime() > start.getTime() && date.getTime() < end.getTime()) {
      currentHour = i
      remainingTime = end.getTime() - date.getTime()
      currentPeriod = ([schoolBellTime[i], schoolBellTime[i+1]]).join('-')
    }
  }
  return {current: currentHour, currentPeriod: currentPeriod, remaining: Math.round(remainingTime * 0.0000166667)}
}

console.log(getInfoSchoolTime())
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a somewhat different approach, both to the code and the API.  It uses two helper functions.  Each should be obvious with a single example:  `pad(7) //=> "07"` and `pairs(['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'qux']) //=> [['foo', 'bar'], ['bar', 'baz'], ['baz', 'qux']]`.

The main function takes a list of bell times and returns a function which itself accepts a date object and returns the sort of output you're looking for (period, remaining time in period.)  This API makes it much easier to test.

```js
const pad = nbr => ('00' + nbr).slice(-2)
const pairs = vals => vals.reduce((res, val, idx) => idx < 1 ? res : res.concat([[vals[idx - 1], val]]), [])

const schoolPeriods = (schoolBellTime) => {
  const subtractTimes = (t1, t2) => 60 * t1.hour + t1.minute - (60 * t2.hour + t2.minute)
  const periods = pairs(schoolBellTime.map(time => ({hour: time.split(':')[0], minute: +time.split(':')[1]})))
  
  return date => {
    const current = {hour: date.getHours(), minute: date.getMinutes()}
    if (subtractTimes(current, periods[0][0]) < 0) {
      return {message: 'before school day'}
    }
    if (subtractTimes(current, periods[periods.length - 1][1]) > 0) {
      return {message: 'after school day'}
    }
    const idx = periods.findIndex(period => subtractTimes(current, period[0]) >= 0 && subtractTimes(period[1], current) > 0)
    const period = periods[idx]
    return {
      current: idx + 1,
      currentPeriod: `${period[0].hour}:${pad(period[0].minute)} - ${period[1].hour}:${pad(period[1].minute)}`,
      remaining: subtractTimes(period[1], current)
    }
  }
}

const getPeriod = schoolPeriods(["8:10","9:02","9:54","9:59","10:51","11:43","11:58","12:48","13:35","13:40","14:10","14:10","15:02","15:54"])

console.log("Using current time")
console.log(getPeriod(new Date()))
console.log("Using a fixed time")
console.log(getPeriod(new Date(2017, 11, 22, 14, 27))) // will Christmas break ever come?!
```

I made a random guess at the behavior you would want if the date is outside the period range.

Internally, it creates a list of period objects that look like

```
[{hour:9, minute: 59}, {hour: 10, minute: 51}]
```

Perhaps it would be cleaner if instead of a two-element array it was an object with `start` and `end` properties.  That would be an easy change.

Do note that for this to make sense, the bells need to be listed in order.  We could fix this with a `sort` call, but I don't see a good reason to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an ES6 example using deconstruct (`const [a,b]=[1,2]`), array map, array reduce, partial application (closure) and fat arrow function syntax.

This may not work in older browsers.

```js
//pass date and bellTimes to function so you can test it more easily
//  you can partially apply bellTimes 
const getInfoSchoolTime = bellTimes => {
  //convert hour and minute to a number
  const convertedBellTimes = bellTimes
    .map(bellTime=>bellTime.split(":"))//split hour and minute
    .map(([hour,minute])=>[new Number(hour),new Number(minute)])//convert to number
    .map(([hour,minute])=>(hour*60)+minute)//create single number (hour*60)+minutes
    .reduce(//zip with next
      (ret,item,index,all)=>
        (index!==all.length-1)//do not do last one, create [1,2][2,3][3,4]...
          ? ret.concat([[item,all[index+1]]])
          : ret,
      []
    );
  return date =>{
    //convert passed in date to a number (hour*60)+minutes
    const passedInTime = (date.getHours()*60)+date.getMinutes();
    return convertedBellTimes.reduce(
      ([ret,goOn],[low,high],index,all)=>
        //if goOn is true and passedInTime between current and next bell item
        (goOn && passedInTime<high && passedInTime>=low)
          ? [//found the item, return object and set goOn to false
              {
                current: index+1,
                currentPeriod: bellTimes[index]+"-"+bellTimes[index+1],
                remaining: high-passedInTime
              },
              false//set goOn to false, do not continue checking
            ]
          : [ret,goOn],//continue looking or continue skipping (if goOn is false)
      [
        {current: 0, currentPeriod: "School is out", remaining: 0},//default value
        true//initial value for goOn
      ]
    )[0];//reduced to multiple values (value, go on) only need value
  }
};

//some tests
const date = new Date();
//partially apply with some bell times
const schoolTime = getInfoSchoolTime(
  [
    "8:10", "9:02", "9:54", "9:59", "10:51",
    "11:43", "11:58", "12:48", "13:35", "13:40",
    "14:10", "14:10", "15:02", "15:54"
  ]
);
//helper to log time from a date
const formatTime = date =>
  ("0"+date.getHours()).slice(-2)+":"+("0"+date.getMinutes()).slice(-2);
date.setHours(11);
date.setMinutes(1);
console.log(formatTime(date),schoolTime(date));//11:01
date.setHours(15);
date.setMinutes(53);
console.log(formatTime(date),schoolTime(date));//15:53
date.setHours(23);
date.setMinutes(1);
console.log(formatTime(date),schoolTime(date));//23:01
```